# Checkbox to change Gridview based on a specific row value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Please forgive me if I do not articulate this in the most comprehensive way, I am new to .net.

What I am trying to do is: Have a checkbox external to a grid-view that once selected, updates the grid-view to ONLY display rows with a certain value. In this case either "YES" or "NO". Once the user selects the checkbox, it will only display rows that have column value of "YES".

I would prefer to do this in a way that does not require recreating the entire grid-view, but rather only displaying the rows that have the "YES" value in them. This is all I've gotten so far and I don't know if I'm on the right path:

```
protected void chkbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppError curError = null;
    User curUser = null;

    if (chkboxlbl.Checked == true) //if checked then jump into next step
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewAppts.Rows)
        {
          // not sure what to put here yet. 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By iterating each row you just need one more step to achieve the objective by setting row visibility to `false`: to find out in which column/cell index that "NO" values are set.

You can use one of two possible solutions below to hide all rows which contains "NO" value in certain column/cell index:

**1) Using `foreach` loop**

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewAppts.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // 'n' belongs to column index, starting from leftmost column = 0
        if (row.Cells[n].Text == "NO")
        {
            row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Using `for` loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridViewAppts.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // 'n' belongs to column index, starting from leftmost column = 0
    if (GridViewAppts.Rows[i].Cells[n].Text == "NO")
    {
        GridViewAppts.Rows[i].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Visible property of the row to False.

```
if(GridViewRow.Column = "NO")
    GridViewRow.Visible = False;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! One more question if you dont mind...I plugged that into the method but im getting a few errors. This is what I have now   ------          try
            {
                if (chkboxlbl.Checked == true) 
                {
                    if(GridViewRow.Column = "NO") GridViewRow.Visible = false;
                }
                else 
                {
                    GridViewRow.Visible = true; 
                }
           }

Comment: Im getting an error stating "GridViewRow does not contain a definition for 'Column'

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
row.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";
```

If that doesn't work then I'd rebind. You could also do it client side.